# how to conditionally call a RTK-query hook in a loop though we cant use it inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, rtk-query

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchServiceProducts = async () => {
    if (isSuccess === true && data) {
      for (let i = 0; i < data?.data.length; i++) {
        const serviceid = data.data[i].service_id;
        console.log(serviceid, "serviceid");
        const { data: serviceProduct } = await useServicedataByidQuery(serviceid).refetch();
        console.log(serviceProduct, "serviceata");
      }
    }
  };
  fetchServiceProducts();
}, []);
```

As we can't add RTKQ hook inside a callback, how do I make this possible and call my query after the loop length is completed and get collected data?

Answer (score 3):

You likely want to be using the "lazy" version of the query. This returns a "trigger" function that can be called at-will. See [useLazyQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) for more details.

Example:

```js
const [trigger] = useLazyServicedataByidQuery(/* query options */);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchServiceProducts = async () => {
    if (isSuccess && data) {
      for (let i = 0; i < data?.data.length; i++) {
        const serviceId = data.data[i].service_id;
        console.log({ serviceId });

        const { data: serviceProduct } = await trigger(serviceId);
        console.log({ serviceProduct });
      }
    }
  };

  fetchServiceProducts();
}, []);
```